# Woocommerce - How to add product variation from external script

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I've a variable product with taxonomy "pa_size" attribute setted with following values: S|M|L|XL

How can I add variation for that product using an external php script?

Thanks in advance.

I use following code:

```
    $sku = 21333;
    $size = 'S';
    $stock = 2;
    $price_a = 60;
    $price_b = 30;

    $product_parent = get_product_by_sku($sku);
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_parent->id);
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // First off all delete all variations
    foreach($variations as $prod_variation) {
      $metaid=mysql_query("SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ".$prod_variation['variation_id']);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($metaid)) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = ".$row['meta_id']);
      }
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = ".$prod_variation['variation_id']);
    }

    // Now add new variation
    $thevariation = array(
      'post_title'=> '',
      'post_name' => 'product-' . $product_parent->id . '-variation',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'post_parent' => $product_parent->id,
      'post_type' => 'product_variation',
      'guid'=>home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $product_parent->id . '-variation'
    );
    $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $thevariation );
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'post_title', 'Variation #' . $variation_id . ' of '. $product_parent->id);

    wp_set_object_terms( $variation_id, $size, 'pa_size' );
    update_post_meta($variation_id, 'attribute_pa_size', $size);

    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_regular_price', $price_a);
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_downloadable_files', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_download_expiry', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_download_limit', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_backorders', 'no');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_height', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_width', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_backorders', 'no');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_height', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_width', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_length', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_weight', '');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_virtual', 'no');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_thumbnail_id', '0');
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_sku', '');

    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_sale_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($variation_id, '_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_variation_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_variation_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_variation_regular_price', $price_a);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_variation_regular_price', $price_a);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_regular_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_regular_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_variation_sale_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_variation_sale_price', $price_b);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_min_sale_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_max_sale_price_variation_id', $variation_id);
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, '_price', $price_b);

    update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock', $stock );
    update_post_meta($product_parent->id, 'post_status', 'publish');
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate. What's in the external script? Why do you need it? Just some things to help people help you.

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking , I need to create variation product to each attribute values using php. Example: for size "S" I want to create variation with 30$ price and 2 stock.

Comment: But why can't you just go into the admin and create an "S" variation that is $30 with 2 in stock? If it helps, note that variations are posts that are children of the variable parent post. So you could just use something like `wp_insert_post()`.

Comment: @helgatheviking I've edited my first post, take a look please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can run an action on `save_post` to do whatever you'd like whenever a post is saved/updated. Or in the case of WooCommerce products you can run it on their `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook which runs on `save_post` but already has some checks in place to make sure it only works on product and the user has the right permissions, etc. Using their hook, we can reduce conditional logic down to checking whether the product is a variable product. If it is, run some custom code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'so_27902470_update_variations', 10, 2 );
function so_27902470_update_variations( $post_id, $post ){
    if( isset( $post['product_type'] ) && 'variable' == $post['product_type'] ){
        // do your stuff
    }
    return $post_id;
}
```